# Order of execution between text and a class-generated table

Tags: php, class, html-table

I have a problem with a HTML table generated with a PHP class and saved into a variable.
This variable also contains text, saved before the table, but the table is displayed before the text.
Here's what I do :

1. Put a text in a variable :

> $RET='Awesome introduction';

2. Generate a table with a class of my own (it's still a simple table) :

> $TAB=new class_table();
>
> $TAB::add_th('Column'); // saves 'Column' in a 'th' 3D array
>
> $TAB::close_line(); // $num_tr++
>
> $TAB::add_td('Cell'); // saves 'Cell' in a 'td' 3D array
>
> $TAB::display(); // generate the table

- When I do this :

> $RET='Awesome introduction';
>
> $RET.=$TAB::display();
>
> echo $RET;

... I've got the table before the text.

- When I do this :

> echo 'Awesome introduction';
>
> $TAB::display();

... I've got the table after the text, and that's correct.

- When I generate my table without the class, it's correct too, of course.

**Do you know if it's normal (maybe the class' call is executed in first ?) and if I can workaround this ?**

I ask because this code is a just a easy sample, the real one is much complex and called with AJAX (and a console.log proves that the table is generated before the text). I hope I'm clear enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, probably Completely normal. This Display class is probably doing exactly that. Displaying, not returning values. You are assigning nothing to the $RET.= , You can prove it by echoing it a second time, it will print your header a second time but not your table. At the time that you assign nothing to RET you output the table, probably with print statements or echo statements in the Display class. There maybe be some way to use the eval function to capture the output of the Display class, but that's above my pay grade.  (This would just be a comment, but i haven't earned the privilege.)

Comment: Thank you very much, you found the solution ! I was using echoes in my display method. I have always used echoes in my display methods and it worked for everything else that this "table" one. Now I'm going to update my other classes and rename the "display" methods to something like "return", to make it easier to understand and to avoid oether mistakes. Thank you again.